# set reduction recursive algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm

Given (A,B,C,D)

What is an algorithm that can reduce it to unique non duplicated sets of size n.

For example if n is 3.

```
[A,B,C]
[A,C,D]
[A,B,D]
[B,C,D]
```

As you'll notice A,A,A cannot be valid neither can A,A,B and [A,C,D] = [C,A,D] = [A,C,D] = [D,C,A] = etc..

is there a way to not generate the powerset and reduce it because a powerset of 7 elements is n^7, which quickly gets exhaustive.

Comment: (1) You are looking for number of combinations, there is plenty of information how to achieve it. (2) There are `Choose(N,k)=n!/(n-k)!k!`, of those. (3) The size of the power set is `2^n`, not `n^n`, so for 7 elements - that's 2^7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Math_Combinatorics](http://pyrus.sourceforge.net/Math_Combinatorics.html).

```
<?php
require 'Combinatorics.php';

$combinatorics = new Math_Combinatorics;
$result = $combinatorics->combinations( ['A','B','C','D'], 3 );
var_export($result);
```

prints

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'A',
    1 => 'B',
    2 => 'C',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'A',
    1 => 'B',
    3 => 'D',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'A',
    2 => 'C',
    3 => 'D',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    1 => 'B',
    2 => 'C',
    3 => 'D',
  ),
)
```

It also has a `permutations` method (i.e. [A,B,C]!=[A,C,B] and therefore both are in the result set)

Comment: hi could you tell me how to install this library for php?

Comment: This package has no dependencies, so you could just download the zip archive and place the combinatorics.php somewhere where if can be "found". PEAR(2) has it's own installer, see http://pear.php.net/manual/en/pyrus.php . But `composer` is on the rise, see http://bioinfornetics.blogspot.de/2014/01/installing-pear-packages-through.html